# How to keep writing value into spreadsheet in a user controlled loop in Python?

Tags: python, csv, timestamp

I'm trying to write values into a .csv file every second until interrupted by the user by pressing a key. I'm able to achieve it in a finite loop. 
I tried using raw_input but the program would only write the last value before interruption. What should I change in my code?

Here's the code that works for a finite loop:

```
import time
import csv

class Timestamp:

    def __init__(self):

        my_file = open('test_csv.csv','w+')

        with my_file:
            new_file = csv.writer(my_file)

        for val in range(0,20):

            with open('test_csv.csv','a') as f:
                date_now = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
                time_now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                to_write = [date_now, time_now]
                csv_file =csv.writer(f)
                csv_file.writerow(to_write)
                time.sleep(1)

Timestamp()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use threads.

```
import time
import csv
from threading import Thread


def write_loop(self):
    my_file = open('test_csv.csv', 'w+')

    with my_file:
        new_file = csv.writer(my_file)

    for val in range(0, 20):
        with open('test_csv.csv', 'a') as f:
            date_now = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
            time_now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            to_write = [date_now, time_now]
            csv_file = csv.writer(f)
            csv_file.writerow(to_write)
            time.sleep(1)


t = Thread(target=write_loop)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

input("Press any key to stop")
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know python has threads.
The program works. How can I achieve the same if I'm creating a button? What should my command be when the button is pressed?

Comment: @Shawn If you have a button and want it to stop a loop, set stop_loop=True, if button is clicked. And on the loop, if stop_loop==True break the loop